# How to fix "PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted" when running python commands?

Tags: apt, sudo, python, zorin

I have installed python 3.11 with command
`sudo apt-get install python3.11`. I am trying to create a new virtual environment for my project in a folder on a USB drive.

But when I actually run command `python3.11 -m venv env` to create the new virtual environment, I get this error:

```
Error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 'lib' -> '/media/pydev19/0D98-7E27/Python/PyClickerX/env/lib64'
```

Running the command with `sudo` returns the same error.

I am on Zorin OS which is built on Ubuntu 20.04. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: err, what's the file sytem you're creating that venv on?

Comment: I am trying to create the venv on a folder in a usb drive

Comment: yes, what is that usb drive formatted with?

Comment: The format for the usb drive is FAT32, I don't know what the drive is formatted with, I having been using it as is when it arrived.

Comment: FAT32 can't work for virtualenvs under Linux, that's what we're seeing here. You will need to put a file system that supports at least POSIX permissions on the drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am on Zorin OS which is built on Ubuntu 20.04. How do I fix this issue?

As discussed in the comments, your drive is FAT32-formatted. That won't do; `venv` expects to be able to set permissions on these files, and FAT32 doesn't have these.

So, to fix that, you need to format your USB drive with a "proper" file system. XFS or ext4 would be natural choices on Linux.

Comment: How would I go about reformatting the drive?

Comment: https://help.zorin.com/docs/getting-started/reuse-your-zorin-os-usb-install-drive/